# Error loading assembly Telerik.WinControls.UI when trying to distribute my application

Tags: c#, telerik, distribution

I need know how can I distribute the project. I am receiving the following error when I attempt to run the project in other PC :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Telerik.WinControls.UI...'.
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Remember to ship the dependencies along with your project, I believe Telerik requires an installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jesus is right: many of these controls are in GAC on your pc so everything works; in your project, in dependencies part, select to copy these DLLs in BIN folder, so you will find the EXE and dlls it needs...
Or, if you're deploying your project with an installer, select those dlls to be installed in GAC (if they are signed with a strong name) or in your application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `Telerik.WinControls.UI....dll` in your setup project into Application Folder.